# APK 'Internet Permission' is missing on SeeTest Automation tool

Tags: java, seetest

Unfortunately after upgrading SeeTest Automation to v 8.7.85, we are getting an  error as 'The APK file should have an Internet permission in order to launch application in instrumented mode'.

We are stuck at this error and have contacted SeeTest team but wasn't fruitful.

Anyone else facing this issue ?

Note: Everything works fine on build 8.4.55, but as per client commitments we need to use latest version available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this looks to be issue in your apk file than SeeTest Automation tool problem (so no surprise that SeeTest tool team weren’t much helpful).

This is something either you or someone from your development team can fix, this issue is due to missing permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file. To fix this, open your `AndoridManifest.xml` and add the below line **before the application tag** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After this try importing the new app into SeeTest, hope this helps.

Comment: Apart from this answer, you can take a look at this- https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/Manually+Instrumenting+Android+Applications . Both appear to be directing towards same root cause.

Comment: Thanks, have informed my Dev team members to incorporate the permissions, will update once it works.